# Adobe Dreamweaver alternatives?

Tags: open-source

I recently ramped up my server security by adding ssh keys but this had brought up some issues, I was then unable to login to my server through Dreamweaver. I looked up some documentation and found out that the version that I currently have (CS6) doesn't support ssh keys, but the new CC edition does, so I decided to find out the pricing of the software suite and the result was shocking, it was way too over price and well over budget.

So my question is...:

Any Dreamweaver alternatives that is extremely good and is free (open source would be amazing)?

It would be awesome if this software had almost all the features that Adobe Dreamweaver has, and also the feature to connect via ssh key.

Any suggestions and help are warmly welcomed!

Sid.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Answer (score 1):

According to my findings, I would recommend [Aptana Studio 3](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download.html).

> Aptana Studio is an open source integrated development environment
>   (IDE) for building web applications. Based on Eclipse, it supports
>   JavaScript, HTML, DOM and CSS with code-completion, outlining,
>   JavaScript debugging, error and warning notifications and integrated
>   documentation. Additional plugins allow Aptana Studio to support Ruby
>   on Rails, PHP, Python, Perl.

Core features:

- HTML, CSS, and JavaScript Code Assist
- Deployment Wizard ( Support for one-shot as well as keep-synchronized setups. Multiple protocols including FTP, SFTP, FTPS and Capistrano)
- Integrated Debugger
- IDE Customization

[image: Screenshots]

If you face problems connecting via SSH please see the workaround described here: [SSH Remote access in Aptana](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26294347)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you very much, Aptana seems to be great, I will surely install it and run it soon!

Comment: If it does what you ask for, please don't forget to come back and accept this answer, as doing so will help others in future